# Using AngularJS $compile on CKEditor contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I am trying to render AngularJS directives within a CKEditor instance Editor area.

Right now, I am able to render the directives unto a separate div block, thanks to some searching here on StackOverflow.

Unfortunately, I am still unable to render it on the preview area itself.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
<div class="widget-body" ng-app="myapp">
    <div compile="ckvalue"></div>
        <form>
            <textarea ck-editor data-ng-model="ckvalue"></textarea>
        </form>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myapp', [], function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
          function(scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
          },
          function(value) {
            element.html(value);

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
        );
      };
    });
  });

angular.module("myapp").directive('ckEditor', function () {
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], {
            allowedContent: true,
            entities: false,
            contentsCss: [CKEDITOR.basePath + 'contents.css', '{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}'],
        } );

      if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      });

      function updateModel() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
          });
      }

      ck.on('change', updateModel);
      ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);
      ck.on('key', updateModel);
      ck.on('paste', updateModel);
      ck.on('selectionChange', updateModel);

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

How can I make it so that it will render the angularjs directives inside the Editor area?